# unexpected behaviour with gregorian calendar with dates B.C

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I would like :

- to set a date to 70 B.C.
- then subtract 2 years
- I expect to have a new date with the value of : 72 B.C.

But I get 68 B.C.

Here my code:

```
GregorianCalendar g1 = new GregorianCalendar();
g1.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, 70);
g1.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, 11);
g1.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
g1.set(GregorianCalendar.ERA, GregorianCalendar.BC);
System.out.println(g1.toString()); 
g1.add(GregorianCalendar.YEAR,-2);
System.out.println(g1.toString());
```

Of course I could simply change -2 to 2 and it will work, but doing the same with dates in A.D. it works the opposite way.

What is the correct way to subtract years from gregorianCalendar independent from the ERA ?

**Additional Info about JDK and System**
- I am on Android 5.1.1

It seems to be a problem in Android only ?

Comment: I can say that this work on Java 6. (1.6.0_23)

Comment: It's 72 BC on JDK 8. http://ideone.com/u5rA7v

Comment: What is your JDK version ?

Comment: Please specify platform details like OS, java version. Also, try to use Calendar g1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); instead of using 'new' operator.

Comment: On Android (with Java 7) it returns also 68... It seems if you set the year to a negative number it switches the era to BC; but if you change the era to BC after setting the year it does not change the year...

Comment: @Massimo : I am on Android. It seems to be a bug ? How to come over this. Just switching to A.D. before subtracting and then back to B.C. ?

Comment: No, it seems you should use negative numbers for BC years (and use the era only by reading it)

Comment: Hi Massimo. Sorry but I didn't understand. Can you do a sample ?